# Launching Google Maps intent for directions requires 3 back button presses to return to my app

Tags: android, android-maps

I'm launching google maps from my app like so

```
String link = "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+sLat+","+sLong+"&daddr="+dLat+","+dLong+"&sensor=true";
Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link));
myIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
main.startActivity(myIntent);
```

However, is there a better way to launch into the start navigation activity so that if the user hits the back button once it returns to my app?

Comment: Where does it go to on button pushes 1 and 2 then?

Comment: The intent takes you to the screen with the full map with the start button in the lower right hand corner. On first back button it zooms out the map to the route options page with the "Start Navigation" link. On second back button it take me to the regular maps activity as if I'd launched it from scratch. Then last goes back to my app (with some strange overlay that I have to toggle the screen to refresh -- separate issue though)

Comment: I don't think you can have any control of the first two pushes then, as they are being implemented by the maps app, not yours. I can't see a way round it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of this question, but I will show you the answer. You can implement a chat head to create an icon that can return to the previous activity Here is the solution:

### Service:

```
public class ChadHeadService extends Service {
private WindowManager mWindowManager;
private View mChatHeadView;

public ChadHeadService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //Inflate the chat head layout we created
    mChatHeadView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_chat_head, null);

    //Add the view to the window.
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    //Specify the chat head position
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;        //Initially view will be added to top-left corner
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 400;

    //Add the view to the window
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mWindowManager.addView(mChatHeadView, params);

    //Set the close button.
    /*ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) mChatHeadView.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //close the service and remove the chat head from the window
            stopSelf();
        }
    });*/

    //Drag and move chat head using user's touch action.
    final ImageView chatHeadImage = (ImageView) mChatHeadView.findViewById(R.id.chat_head_profile_iv);
    chatHeadImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private int lastAction;
        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    //remember the initial position.
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;

                    //get the touch location
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();

                    lastAction = event.getAction();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //As we implemented on touch listener with ACTION_MOVE,
                    //we have to check if the previous action was ACTION_DOWN
                    //to identify if the user clicked the view or not.
                    if (lastAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        //Open the chat conversation click.
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ChadHeadService.this, "ACTIVYTY RETURN");
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        //close the service and remove the chat heads
                        stopSelf();
                    }
                    lastAction = event.getAction();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //Calculate the X and Y coordinates of the view.
                    params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);

                    //Update the layout with new X & Y coordinate
                    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mChatHeadView, params);
                    lastAction = event.getAction();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mChatHeadView != null) mWindowManager.removeView(mChatHeadView);
}
```

}

**Start App:**

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+adrees+"&mode=d");
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            try {
                context.startActivity(mapIntent);
                context.startService(new Intent(context, ChadHeadService.class));
            }
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
                try {
                    context.startActivity(mapIntent);
                    context.startService(new Intent(context, ChadHeadService.class));
                }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Application not installed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```